# Making an API request every X amount of seconds in reactJS

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, async-await, promise, setinterval

On entering **CurrencyPage**, I am trying to get the list of currencyConversionRates from database and then subsequently set an interval to constantly get the new updated list of currencyConversionRates every 6 seconds.

Up till this point, everything works fine. However, I am unable to pass the value of the setInterval to the cleanup function. The value being returned is always in the format of a promise

```
Promise {<fulfilled>: 1}
```

How can I pass the setInterval value to the cleanup function so that the interval stops being executed upon navigating to other pages

**Use Effect**

```
useEffect(() => {
    const getCurrencyConversionRates=async()=>{
        console.log("Retrieving list of currency conversion rate");
        await retrieveCurrencyConversionRateFunction();

        //Gets new information every 6 seconds
        const intervalCall = setInterval(async() => {
            console.log("Getting new currency conversion rates!");
            const currTime = new Date().toLocaleTimeString();
            console.log("Time -> "+currTime);
            await retrieveCurrencyConversionRateFunction();
        }, 60*100);


        //Have to wait until currencyConversionRateFunction is loaded before the map function is called on it in the render view otherwise will have error
        setLoading(false);
        return intervalCall;
    }

    let intervalCall = getCurrencyConversionRates();
    //Clear interval
    return () => {
        console.log("CLEARING CURRENCY INTERVAL HERE");
        console.log(intervalCall);
        clearInterval(intervalCall);
      };

},[]);
```

***Solution*** Based on **Azzy's** answer
Rather than to try and return the interval in `getCurrencyConversionRates()`, a simple alternative is to just initialize a variable to store the setInterval as it is created within the function.

Note to self -> It is not possible to pass a variable by reference through `getCurrencyConversionRates()` as a parameter as changes made to the variable wont be saved. However, in JS you can simply initialize the variable outside of the function and modify it's value from within the function.

https://www.javascripttutorial.net/javascript-pass-by-value/

```
useEffect(() => {
    
    const getCurrencyConversionRates=async()=>{
        // console.log("Retrieving list of currency conversion rate");
        await retrieveCurrencyConversionRateFunction();

        //Gets new information every 6 seconds
        intervalCall = setInterval(async() => {
            // console.log("Getting new currency conversion rates!");
            const currTime = new Date().toLocaleTimeString();
            console.log("Time -> "+currTime);
            await retrieveCurrencyConversionRateFunction();
        }, 60*100);


        //Have to wait until currencyConversionRateFunction is loaded before the map function is called on it in the render view otherwise will have error
        setLoading(false);
        // return intervalCall;
    }

    let intervalCall;
    getCurrencyConversionRates();

    //Clear interval
    return () => {
        console.log("CLEARING CURRENCY INTERVAL HERE");
        console.log(intervalCall);
        clearInterval(intervalCall);
      };

},[]);
```

Comment: You have to await for it. Every thing returned from an async function is a promise

Comment: @Konrad but i cant await getCurrencyConversionRates(); i cant make useEffect async

Comment: You could store the interval id in a ref so that you don’t have to wait for the function to return it

Comment: @PhantomSpooks can you give an example? is it like storing it in a state?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will help

```
useEffect(() => {

   let isValid = true;

   let intervalCall;

    const getCurrencyConversionRates = async () => {
        console.log("Retrieving list of currency conversion rate");
        await retrieveCurrencyConversionRateFunction();
        // after await if the component unmounts, and this scope 
        // becomes stale, skip futher execution   
        // so the interval wont be started, and wont break in dev mode where useEffect runs twice
        if (!isValid) { return; } 

        //Gets new information every 6 seconds
         intervalCall = setInterval( async () => {
            console.log("Getting new currency conversion rates!");
            const currTime = new Date().toLocaleTimeString();
            console.log("Time -> "+currTime);
            await retrieveCurrencyConversionRateFunction();

            // might want to check valid scope inside 
            // retrieveCurrencyConversionRateFunction 
            // by passing it a flag to skip execution on a unmounted component scope

        }, 60*100);


        //Have to wait until currencyConversionRateFunction is loaded before the map function is called on it in the render view otherwise will have error
        setLoading(false);
    }

    getCurrencyConversionRates();
    //Clear interval
    return () => {
        console.log("CLEARING CURRENCY INTERVAL HERE");
        isValid = false
    
        // if interval was not stared, dont clear it
        if (intervalCall) {  clearInterval(intervalCall); } 
        console.log(intervalCall);
       
      };

},[]);
```

more about [useEffect life cycle](https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/lifecycle-of-reactive-effects), to get an idea why

- A new effect is created after every render
- The cleanup for previous effect occurs before executing of current `useEffect`

You can read about why isValid is set [synchronizing with effects](https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/synchronizing-with-effects#fetching-data)

If you are intererested in taking a deep dive, consider reading a blog post by [Dan on useEffect](https://overreacted.io/a-complete-guide-to-useeffect/#each-render-has-its-own-everything), its old but explans the details to build a good mental model about `useEffect` and functional components.

Hope it helps, cheers

Comment: It works! but can you explain the logic behind it

Comment: After testing your solution , I realized you could simply set the value of variable intervalCall from the subfunction retrieveCurrencyConversionRateFunction() despite being on a different scope. 

I tried passing the variable in by parameter and editing it by reference but it didnt work hence i thought it wouldnt be possible

Comment: I edited the answer with brief explanation and links to new docs, but I am trying to understand the new point, and if it could interval not being cleared

Comment: Yes you can optimize the solution, the answer is ment to be simple enough to explain what is going in

Comment: I have edited my question to include the solution that i have used which is a modification to your suggested answer. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Welcome, glad you where able solve the problem